# What is .net hierarchy for loading of system configuration properties

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-3.5, configurationmanager

I have a general question, but I'll also explain why I'm asking so you can get a better idea of what I mean.

I have a dll that has a webservice url defined in Settings, and at runtime it uses Settings.Default to get the url from settings.  However, none of our environments have a (dllName).dll.config file, and the specific setting is not defined in the (exeName).exe.config of the calling application.  It's really clear that the default value isn't being used, because it's set to some internal IP address; yet this works in production where they don't have this setting defined in any .config file that I can find, and it's still hitting the correct webservice URL somehow.  I need to know where the value is being loaded from in this case.

So my more broad question is, how does the hierarchy work for loading settings in .net?  For example, does it look in machine.config first, then (exeName).exe.config, and the if it's a dll it would go to (dllName).dll.config?  Where does it look first, and what order does it look in other places, and are there any other places I didn't mention that this config could be defined?

Also, for a DLL, if you have something defined in Settings, does that get embedded in the compiled dll as a default value, and is that used if the property isn't found in any other .config file?

Comment: Something like this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: Its good link from @t3hn00b. It should be an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The hierarchical nature of .NET configuration provides a great level
>   of flexibility, allowing specific users or locations to have their own
>   configuration settings. However, those configuration settings are not
>   isolated and duplicate settings made at a more specific level have the
>   ability to override settings made at a less specific level. As can be
>   seen in picture, the most specific configuration files are merged into
>   the less specific, with the most specific settings overriding the
>   least specific. In the Exe context, User (or to be more precise, Local
>   User) settings are most specific, followed by Roaming User (shared
>   between two or more machines), Application and, finally, Machine.

[image: Config hierarchy and merging]

I suggest you to read following article, because your answer is just a citation:

- [Cracking the Mysteries of NET Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)

And usefull will be:

- [Unraveling the Mysteries of NET Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)
- [Decoding the Mysteries of NET Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16724/Decoding-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)

Comment: unless that image  and accompaying text is your own, please give appropriate attribution.

Comment: yes i know, comment still applies. this answer just a cut/paste from that article

Comment: @wal answer was with references. And when answer is part of MSDN article or any other article, think citation will be good enough, especially on "broad questions".

Comment: if you didnt type that text out yourself you should quote it.

Comment: @wal Please read carefully. It's quoted but textually. I've forgotten about quote tag here, so will add one. References could be added also with words a-la "citation" or "quotation ".