# Find out which web.config(s) have been loaded

Tags: c#, web-config, webconfigurationmanager

I'm encountering an error indicating that the web.config being loaded by this particular sub-project of my solution has a connectionstring that conflicts with an existing entry from an already-loaded web.config 
(Exception message is: *Additional information: The entry 'connStr' has already been added.*)

Is there a way to easily find out the list of all web.configs loaded/being loaded, so that I can ascertain where to conflict is arising

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, I think this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114336/what-is-net-hierarchy-for-loading-of-system-configuration-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one web.config that will be loaded, however, it will inherit from your machine configuration. For IIS this is here:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG\machine.config
```

And for IIS Express in one of these places:

```
%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config
%userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config
$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config (only for Visual Studio 2015 and above)
```

So you can remove the duplicate from there, or add a `remove` entry in your `web.config`, for example:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="MyConnection" />
  <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: For local IIS it is `%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before, I added  `inheritInChildApplications="false"` in my main web.config. This way I know that my sub web.config will not have any conflict.